# Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'id<UIDocumentPickerDelegate> _Nullable' with an lvalue of type 'const Class'というエラーが出る

Tags: swift, xcode, objective-c

XcodeをXcode12.5にアップデートすると、今まで普通にビルドできていたライブラリが使用できなくなりました。
Xcode12.4以前では問題なかった気がします。

エラー内容は以下のようなものです。

```
Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'id<UIDocumentPickerDelegate> _Nullable' with an lvalue of type 'const Class'
```

コードはObjective-Cで書かれている以下の部分です。

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

typedef void (*callbackFunc)(const char *);
static callbackFunc asyncCallback;

@interface  StandaloneFileBrowser : NSObject<UIDocumentPickerDelegate>
+ (void)    createOpenPanel:(NSString*)title
            directory:(NSString*)directory
            filters:(NSString*)filters
            multiselect:(BOOL)multiselect
            canChooseFiles:(BOOL)canChooseFiles
            canChooseFolders:(BOOL)canChooseFolders
            save:(BOOL)save;
@end

extern "C" {
    const char* DialogOpenFilePanel(const char* title,
                                    const char* directory,
                                    const char* filters,
                                    bool multiselect);
    void DialogOpenFilePanelAsync(const char* title,
                                  const char* directory,
                                  const char* filters,
                                  bool multiselect,
                                  callbackFunc cb);
    const char* DialogOpenFolderPanel(const char* title,
                                      const char* directory,
                                      bool multiselect);
    void DialogOpenFolderPanelAsync(const char* title,
                                    const char* directory,
                                    bool multiselect,
                                    callbackFunc cb);
    const char* DialogSaveFilePanel(const char* title,
                                    const char* directory,
                                    const char* defaultName,
                                    const char* filters);
    void DialogSaveFilePanelAsync(const char* title,
                                  const char* directory,
                                  const char* defaultName,
                                  const char* filters,
                                  callbackFunc cb);
    UIViewController* UnityGetGLViewController();
}

const char* DialogOpenFilePanel(const char* title,
                                const char* directory,
                                const char* filters,
                                bool multiselect) {
    return 0;
    
}

void DialogOpenFilePanelAsync(const char* title,
                              const char* directory,
                              const char* filters,
                              bool multiselect,
                              callbackFunc cb) {
    asyncCallback = cb;
    [StandaloneFileBrowser  createOpenPanel:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:title ?: ""]
                            directory:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:directory ?: ""]
                            filters:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:filters ?: ""]
                            multiselect:multiselect
                            canChooseFiles:YES
                            canChooseFolders:NO
                            save:NO];
}

const char* DialogOpenFolderPanel(const char* title,
                                  const char* directory,
                                  bool multiselect) {
    return 0;
}

void DialogOpenFolderPanelAsync(const char* title,
                                const char* directory,
                                bool multiselect,
                                callbackFunc cb) {
    asyncCallback = cb;
    [StandaloneFileBrowser  createOpenPanel:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:title ?: ""]
                            directory:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:directory ?: ""]
                            filters:@""
                            multiselect:multiselect
                            canChooseFiles:NO
                            canChooseFolders:YES
                            save:NO];
}

const char* DialogSaveFilePanel(const char* title,
                                const char* directory,
                                const char* defaultName,
                                const char* filters) {
    return 0;
}

void DialogSaveFilePanelAsync(const char* title,
                              const char* directory,
                              const char* defaultName,
                              const char* filters,
                              callbackFunc cb) {
    asyncCallback = cb;
    [StandaloneFileBrowser  createOpenPanel:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:title ?: ""]
                            directory:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:directory ?: ""]
                            filters:@""
                            multiselect:NO
                            canChooseFiles:YES
                            canChooseFolders:NO
                            save:YES];
}

@implementation StandaloneFileBrowser
+ (void)    documentPicker:(UIDocumentPickerViewController *)controller
            didPickDocumentsAtURLs:(NSArray <NSURL *>*)urls {
    NSString* pathsStr = @"";
    NSMutableArray* paths = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[urls count]];
    for (int i = 0; i <  [urls count]; i++) {
        NSURL* url = [urls objectAtIndex:i];
        [paths addObject:[url path]];
    }
    NSString* seperator = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", 28];
    pathsStr = [paths componentsJoinedByString:seperator];
    if (asyncCallback) {
        asyncCallback([pathsStr UTF8String]);
    }
}
+ (void)    documentPicker:(UIDocumentPickerViewController *)controller
            didPickDocumentAtURL:(NSURL *)url {
    NSString* pathsStr = @"";
    NSMutableArray* paths = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:1];
    [paths addObject:[url path]];
    NSString* seperator = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", 28];
    pathsStr = [paths componentsJoinedByString:seperator];
    if (asyncCallback) {
        asyncCallback([pathsStr UTF8String]);
    }
}
+ (void)        createOpenPanel:(NSString*)title
                      directory:(NSString*)directory
                        filters:(NSString*)filters
                    multiselect:(BOOL)multiselect
                 canChooseFiles:(BOOL)canChooseFiles
               canChooseFolders:(BOOL)canChooseFolders
                           save:(BOOL)save
{
        NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:directory];
        NSMutableArray* fileTypes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        if (canChooseFiles) {
            [fileTypes addObject:@"public.item"];
        }
        if (canChooseFolders) {
            [fileTypes addObject:@"public.directory"];
        }
        UIDocumentPickerViewController *controller = [[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc]
                                                      initWithDocumentTypes:fileTypes
                                                      inMode:save?UIDocumentPickerModeExportToService:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];
        [controller setTitle:title];
        [controller setDirectoryURL:url];
        [controller setAllowsMultipleSelection:multiselect];
        [controller setShouldShowFileExtensions:true];
        [controller setDelegate:self];
        [UnityGetGLViewController() presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}
@end
```

エラーが出てる箇所は、下から４行目あたりの以下の部分です。

```
[controller setDelegate:self];
```

エラーを修正する方法はありますでしょうか？

Comment: あなたのコードでは`@interface  StandaloneFileBrowser : NSObject<UIDocumentPickerDelegate>`と、`StandaloneFileBrowser`のインスタンスが`UIDocumentPickerDelegate`プロトコルに適合しているかのように宣言していますが、実際には`StandaloneFileBrowser`にはプロトコルに適合するためのインスタンスメソッドは定義されていません。問題の箇所では`self`は`[StandaloneFileBrowser class]`を表すので、インスタンスではありません。「Xcode12.4以前では問題なかった気がします」とありますが、本当にあなたには「問題なかった気がします」なだけで、問題大有りなのに過去のコンパイラや実行時コードが問題を検出できなかっただけ、と言えるでしょう。なぜそんな変な書き方になっているのかわかりませんが、`UIDocumentPickerDelegate`用のメソッドはインスタンスメソッドに変更した上で、問題の箇所は`self`ではなく、シングルトンインスタンスを渡すよう修正するといった変更が必要でしょう。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。Objective-Cにあまり詳しくないので修正方法が分からないのですが、具体的にどのように修正すれば良いか伺うことはできますでしょうか...？ここに載せたコードだけでは厳しいでしょうか？

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。残念ながらこちらの環境ではご提示のコードに修正を施して動くかどうかどころか、コンパイルが通るかどうかも確認できません。Objective-Cに詳しい方で同じ環境をお持ちの方に相談してみてください。